# Is 'from' correct in this expression?

Tags: prepositions

> I did not really attend the online conference, but I knew what they were doing **from/through** the conversation I had (with someone) earlier.

Which of these (*from/through*) is correct preposition?

Comment: _From the conversation_.

Comment: @BarrieEngland  many thanks for your answer!! Can you please explain to me difference between these two?

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary?

Comment: Elaborate more on your future questions. If you want people to explain more, then ask for more, and provide them with more information.

Comment: It is not impossible to use *through* instead of *from* there. The latter is by far the more common usage, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage would "from" because the word through is usually used to describe movement. This movement can be through space *or* time but it would not work in this situation. The word from can also describe movement, but it can also be used correctly in this case.